# Paramiko: Module object has no attribute error 'SSHClient'

Tags: python, attributes, paramiko

What I found was that if you name your file "paramiko.py" you get this error, but I named my file something else and I still get the same error. I really have no idea what I did wrong, I'm fairly confident I installed PyCrypto and Paramiko successfully.

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect('127.0.0.1', username='meelo_rw', password='')
```

Running this on Windows 8.1.

Comment: I get the same exact error. help(paramiko) also gives the same error, which is really strange. This leads me to believe that something went wrong with installation. But when type `pip install paramiko` into the command prompt it says Requirement already satisfied, which I think means it's installed correctly.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your file is still named `paramiko.py` or there is another file named like that... just for a test, let's start fresh. Open a command prompt, open the interactive python interpreter (just type `python.exe`, and then try to import it and see if `dir(paramiko)` works.

Comment: try `print paramiko.__file__` and see if its the one you think it is. If you had a paramiko.py, you may still have a paramiko.pyc lying around.

Comment: ....or is the error during `import paramiko` itself? Yeah, look for an old paramiko.pyc.

Comment: Okay yea there was a paramiko.pyc file I found. WOOPS. But now I'm getting the error `no module named ecdsa`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just to close off the question... if you have a module named paramiko.py that tries to import paramiko, you run the risk that it will try to import itself instead of the real paramiko module. You can rename your module to fix the problem, but be sure to remove the .pyc file also. Python will continue to import the "compiled" .pyc file in preference to the real module.

Comment: I had the same problem. After I renamed my script from paramiko.py to paramikochico, everything worked again. So simple, but yet so... well... :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have nay file in your local system by the name of "paramiko". The code is going to import that paramiko instead of the python paramiko. You need to rename the file simply and the error will be gone.

Comment: Is that not just a repetition of the already upvoted, accepted, 8 years old answer?